# Hey man what browser would you use if you had a note3 tmobile also I have no sim card

Tags: wireless-networking

Can I still make calls without a sim card and no service provider?   Can I hack my phone so it always picks up wifis is that even feasible with today's techniques?  I work in a timewarner building and they have a wifi for employees that logs you in with an employee email/ username and password. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if T-Mobile lock down Note 3's but I can answer your questions in regards to general Android phones.

Yes you can make VoIP calls without a SIM card. As long as you are connected to a wifi network that can access the VoIP network then you can make a call. You can use whichever VoIP provider you want whether it be an all in one provider like Skype or a more do it yourself SIP provider.

There are apps available such as [Auto open Wi-Fi connection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=assafpassal.apps.openwififree&hl=en) which will connect you to the nearest open wifi network and you will be able to connect your phone to your employer's wifi using your login credentials. Probably best if you talk to your IT Department if you have any trouble with that.

I hope this helps answer your questions.